# React Native Text Input with Border and always Focused

Tags: react-native

[image: Anyone knows to how archive this ?]

I'm trying to implement this type of text input, anyone has an idea to how to implement this ?

Comment: Have you tried any code?,you will have to do some custom styling with a wrapper. and what do you mean by always focused ?

Comment: yeah I have tried react-native paper TextInput but in here I can't change the border color and border width

Comment: Try react-native-textinput-effects and react-native-material-textfield

Comment: You can change the colors of react-native-paper using themes

Comment: borderRadius, borderWidth, borderColor always worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a customInput like this, you will have to switch to props, currently I have hardcoded the values

```
const CustomTextInput = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 10,
          zIndex: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
        }}>
        Phone
      </Text>
      <View
        style={{
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'red',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          borderRadius: 10,
          paddingHorizontal:5,
          paddingTop: 5,
        }}>
        <AntDesign
          name="star"
          size={20}
          color="black"
          style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
        />
        <TextInput value="12313" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Output would be like
[image]

You can change the styles anyway you want.

You can try out the snack here
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/custominput